# How to allocate struct with ANYSIZE_ARRAY?

Tags: winapi, rust, ffi

I'm working on HID Device API in Rust. I'm stuck on trying to get device path using Windows API.

I'm using the [winapi](https://docs.rs/winapi/latest/winapi/) crate function `SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetailA` that takes pointer to struct [`SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA_A`](https://github.com/retep998/winapi-rs/blob/2f76bdea3a79817ccfab496fbd1786d5a697387b/src/um/setupapi.rs#L381), which should be populated with device path, however the `DevicePath` field is an array of fixed size 1 ([`ANYSIZE_ARRAY`](https://github.com/retep998/winapi-rs/blob/2f76bdea3a79817ccfab496fbd1786d5a697387b/src/um/winnt.rs#L19)).

```rust
STRUCT! {
    #[cfg_attr(target_arch = "x86", repr(packed))]
    struct SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA_A {
        cbSize: DWORD,
        DevicePath: [CHAR; ANYSIZE_ARRAY],
    }
}
```

`GetLastError` returns `ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER` which totally makes sense.

What is proper way of allocating memory for a struct in such case ?

Comment: Are we just supposed to know what `ANYSIZE_ARRAY`, or `STRUCT!`, or any other non-standard thing in this question is without context?

Comment: @mcarton I've added links to relevant source code parts from winapi crate.

Comment: As an aside, you may want to call `SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetailW` instead…

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about ‘proper’, but then Rust does not exactly have good support for dynamically-sized structures; this may change when work on [`DynSized`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2984) (which in its current state can be described as ‘not fully defined’) is finalized.  For now, expect lots of `unsafe`.

Going by Microsoft’s documentation for [`SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetailA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/setupapi/nf-setupapi-setupdigetdeviceinterfacedetaila):

> Using this function to get details about an interface is typically a two-step process:
>
> 1. Get the required buffer size. Call **SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail** with a **NULL** *DeviceInterfaceDetailData* pointer, a *DeviceInterfaceDetailDataSize* of zero, and a valid *RequiredSize* variable. In response to such a call, this function returns the required buffer size at *RequiredSize* and fails with GetLastError returning ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER.
> 2. Allocate an appropriately sized buffer and call the function again to get the interface details.

As such, first you need to query the size you need to allocate for the structure.

```rust
use std::{ptr, mem};

let required_size = {
    let mut required_size = mem::MaybeUninit::uninit();

    let ok = SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetailA(
        device_info_set,
        device_iface_data,
        ptr::null_mut(),
        0,
        required_size.as_mut_ptr(),
        ptr::null_mut()
    );
    
    assert!(!ok && GetLastError() == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER);

    required_size.assume_init()
};
```

Then, allocate the buffer to contain the structure.  Below, I use `Vec<u8>`.  Because `Vec` is not guaranteed to allocate memory to any given alignment, I take account of that by adding some padding and offsetting the pointer.  (In practice, I would expect the offset to be zero most of the time, but I cannot rely on that.)

```rust
let mut buf: Vec<u8> = Vec::with_capacity(
    TryInto::<usize>::try_into(required_size).unwrap() +
    mem::align_of::<SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA_A>() - 1);

let align_offset = 
    buf.as_mut_ptr().align_offset(
        mem::align_of::<SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA_A>());

assert!(
    align_offset < (buf.capacity() -
        TryInto::<usize>::try_into(required_size).unwrap())
);

let device_iface_detail = unsafe {
    &mut *(buf.as_mut_ptr().offset(align_offset.try_into().unwrap())
        as *mut mem::MaybeUninit<SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA_A>)
};
```

After allocating, fill the buffer with initial data:

```rust
device_iface_detail.write(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA_A {
    cbSize: mem::size_of::<SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA_A>().try_into().unwrap(),
    DevicePath: [0],
});
```

Now call `SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetailA` again to actually obtain the data you require:

```rust
let ok = unsafe {
    SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetailA(
        device_info_set,
        device_iface_data,
        device_iface_detail.as_mut_ptr(),
        required_size,
        ptr::null_mut(),
        ptr::null_mut() // XXX: or actually put a pointer to a structure here
    )
}
```

Finally, extract the device path from the buffer:

```rust
if ok {
    let path = unsafe {
        std::ffi::CStr::from_ptr(
            ptr::addr_of!(device_iface_detail.assume_init_ref().DevicePath)
            as *const std::os::raw::c_char
        )
    };
    
    /* ... use path and devinfo_data.assume_init_mut() ... */
}
```

The `path` will be usable as long as `buf` stays in scope.  If you want to keep it for longer, you will need to copy it into a `CString` or some other owning container.

Answer (score 0):

There are many `SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail` examples. Also according to [SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetailA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/setupapi/nf-setupapi-setupdigetdeviceinterfacedetaila#remarks),

> Using this function to get details about an interface is typically a
> two-step process:
>
> 1. Get the required buffer size. Call SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail with a NULLDeviceInterfaceDetailData pointer, a
>    DeviceInterfaceDetailDataSize of zero, and a valid RequiredSize
>    variable. In response to such a call, this function returns the
>    required buffer size at RequiredSize and fails with GetLastError
>    returning ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER.
> 2. Allocate an appropriately sized buffer and call the function again to get the interface details.
> 3. Set DeviceInterfaceDetailData.cbSize to sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA) before calling this function.